# How to reach time points clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering

What I met a problem is I do time-series clustering, and I found the clustering result isn't ideal.

I can't use elbow method to know what clustering result is good, that means I have no ways to watch the clustering results and tune parameters.

What I want to do is cluster the same trends data into the same group.

But I met a problem like below:

```
>> arr # It's a time-series array with 10 time intervals.
array([[  0,   0,   100, 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 100,   0],
       [100,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])

>> model = KM(n_clusters=2).fit(arr) ; model.labels_
array([1, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

It clusters `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` the same group!

But!With our eye watching, we all know `arr[0]` and `arr[2]` should be the same group because they have `100` in the near time intervals.

How to do time-points clustering? And specify `random_state=N` is useless becuase there is always one corner case to let me fail.

**UPDATE:**

There's one algorithm to solve this and its name is **KShape**. It can be found in **tslearn** github.

It clusters time-series data based on the shape of each data, so it match my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In k-means there is no similarity or order of axes. They are all assumed to be independent. Hence, these three series are all equally dissimilar. You got what you asked for - but the question you asked (minimize the squared errors in each component) was not what you wanted.

You'll need to choose a different algorithm. One that knows about time, and allows for some tolerance in time, or one where you can use a distance function such as DTW to measure similarity.

Don't treat clustering as a black box. That will not work, you'll get results that you don't like. Instead, understand the algorithms first, then guide them carefully to solve your problem.

Comment: +1 for understanding the question, I got it after reading your answer!

Comment: BTW, There's a tool to solve this, it's KShape and it can be found in tslearn github. It cluster by the shape of time-series data.